# Using Zend GData, How do i get a worksheet cell index by looking for its value?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs, gdata

suppose i have a cell in a worksheet that has a value of "last data cell"
is this the correct way to get the index of this cell (i.e A5) using Zend GData ?

```
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($this->_spreadsheetKey);
$query->setWorksheetId($worksheet);

$cellFeed = $this->_spreadsheetService->getCellFeed($query);

foreach($cellFeed as $cellEntry) {
      $row = $cellEntry->getCell()->getRow();
      $col = $cellEntry->getCell()->getColumn();
      $val = $cellEntry->getCell()->getText();
      if ($val == 'last data cell'){ $index = array($row, $col); }
      //echo "$row, $col = $val\n";
}
return  $index;
```

i want to use the $index value later as a boundaries to define a range, like this for example:

```
$range = (string)$index[0]+1 + $index[1].":F20";
$contentAsCells = $worksheet->getContentsAsCells($range);
```

but the index value is numeric. how do i convert it to the "A1" format ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell ID like this:

```
$cellId = $row . $col; //vars from your code above.
echo $cellId;
```

If $col is 'A' and $row is 1 this will output

> A1

Comment: That's strange according to the docblock for Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_Cell::getColumn() it should return a string.