# Display the content of a google sheet cell in a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My question is essentially the same as that asked here: [display the content of a google sheet cell in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699589/display-the-content-of-a-google-sheet-cell-in-a-web-page)

Another question that is probably relevant is this one, though I don't think it relates to google spreadsheets: [Embedding Google Apps Script WebApp in WordPress Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350485/embedding-google-apps-script-webapp-in-wordpress-page)

My question though relates to displaying a single cell from a google spreadsheet at html in a *wordpress* page?  Or does the method only work for google sites?

If its only google sites, any suggestions on alternative methods achieving this on a wordpress page?

Comment: Your linked question says the cell contains HTML - is that also true in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to display content from google spreadsheet in a wordpress site. You can use the PHP library for the Spreadsheets API. The library is part of the Zend framework - http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest. Download the Zend_Gdata, install the library in your template folder. It is good idea to authenticate and make your api calls from a custom template page. Otherwise you have to use a plugin that executes php code. You can check this entry, too - [Using Zend GData, How do i get a worksheet cell index by looking for its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089041/using-zend-gdata-how-do-i-get-a-worksheet-cell-index-by-looking-for-its-value) or here - [Retrieve only specific columns of spreadsheet with zend gdata from gdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531777/retrieve-only-specific-columns-of-spreadsheet-with-zend-gdata-from-gdocs), or Check the manual provided by Zend - http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html

Comment: awesome, many thanks for that Vasko.  I'll need someone more techy than me to implement this, but I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the value of a Google sheets cell using a specially constructed URL like this: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$google_spreadsheet_ID/values/$location?&key=$api_key`

Where:

```
$api_key = Your API key
$google_spreadsheet_ID = Your spreadsheet ID
$location = The sheet name and cell name (or a named range).
```

The results are returned via json which you'll then have to parse. Here's a tutorial on how to do it in WordPress to get the value of just one cell:

https://www.wp-tweaks.com/display-a-single-cell-from-google-sheets-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

From the spreadsheet menu: File-> Publish to the web.
Add the link to wordpress as a iframe.